# Como suprimir mensajes automáticos que surgen al ejecutar codigo? Quiero que no aparezcan al exportar a PDF

Tags: python, jupyter

Estoy limpiando un cuaderno de Jupyter para exportarlo a PDF con nbconvert.

Cuando represento un histograma, debajo aparece un mensaje: "<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>" como podéis ver en la foto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto un codigo simplificado de como ejecuto los histogramas.

```
plt.hist([5,4,1,3,6,4,1,6,5,4,1,2,3,6,5,2,4,4], bins=6,alpha=1, color='blue',  linewidth=0.5, rwidth=0.8)
```

Lo mismo me pasa en esta línea de codigo

```
simar = pd.read_csv("SIMAR.csv",error_bad_lines=False)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema de estos mensajes es que cuando lo exporto a PDF (suprimiendo las lineas de codigo), estos mensajes no se eliminan, como muestro en la fotos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabría como suprimir estos mensajes para que no aparezcan en mi PDF?

Gracias!

Comment: Cual es tu codigo? Como quieres que te ayudemos si no muestras lo que haces, así no podremos saber que haces mal

Comment: Ya lo tienes actualizado. Gracias

Comment: Hola @christian  Sabrías resolverlo? Gracias

Comment: No he trabajado mucho con Jupyter pero creo que es alguna configuración, lo voy a buscar

Comment: Muchas gracias. Quedo a la espera

Comment: He encontrado esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53132654/how-to-hide-error-messages-in-jupyter-notebook/53132659#53132659) mirala talvez te ayude.